# Insert several gtfs feeds into the same postgis/pgrouting database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, general-transit-feed-specification

I want to import sevaral gtfs feeds into my postgis/pgrouting database so that I can route over all my gtfs feeds.

The problem is that the sources / destinations ids of my gtfs are likely to conflict.

How can I solve this conflict issue?

Comment: Add a feed ID for each gtfs feed and then use a compound key: (feed_id, id)?

Comment: The problem is not for the id but for the source and target fields. Indeed I want to use this [pgrouting function](http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/driving_distance/doc/index.html) on a single database populated with multiple gtfs feeds but the sources/targets from the different feeds should stay isolated so that two edges from different feeds aren't merged.

Comment: So, given this query, `SELECT id, source, target, cost [,reverse_cost] FROM edge_table` can you not change it to: `SELECT id, source, target, cost [,reverse_cost] FROM (select * from edge_table where gtfs_feed=some_id)` then you will only get the nodes and edges for that set. You are providing sql as a paramter, so I would think you could do this.

Comment: The thing is that I want to route on all my feeds at the same time. Not only once.

Comment: Run multiple queries at once then, each with a different route id, or change the source code to do what you want :D.